# Infinite series where each term is the square of the last

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Is there a closed-form, in terms of elementary functions or otherwise, for the power series $x+x^2+x^4+x^8+x^{16}+...$, where each term is the square of the last?

Comment: It satisfies $p(x)=x+p(x^2)$ - not sure that helps much, though

Comment: Not an elementary function.  But an example that is sometime given for a function with natural boundary on the whole unit circle.

Comment: The term *lacunary function* will be helpful when you want to search for related topics, as mentioned by GEdgar.

Answer (score 5):

The series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{\large-2^n}$$

generally does not have a closed form. This is just your series where $x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{x}$.

When $2 \le x \le 10$, the decimal expansion is given by the [OEIS](http://oeis.org).  When $x=2$, the number is called the "[Kempner-Mahler number](http://oeis.org/A007404)." The case when $x=10$ seems to be called the "[Fredholm-Rueppel Sequence](http://oeis.org/A036987)" and has many other interesting properties.

It has also been shown that the number, $M$, generated by the sum $x=2$ is transcendental by Mahler, and [Knight](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324154) showed that this was true for all $x\ge 2$. (Summarized [here](http://escholarship.org/uc/item/44t5s388#page-3))

The continued fraction for this series is discussed for $x \ge 3$ in J. Shallit's "[Simple continued fractions for some irrational numbers](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/scf.ps)."

Comment: Helpful references, Argon. BTW, hello!